# Free pages in Kstat and Sar output

Tags: kernel, solaris, memory, sar

I am trying to find out number of free pages available on Solaris 11. I am using ***kstat*** and ***sar*** utilities. I was comparing their output as follows:
[image]

There is slight difference in the number of free pages being shown by them. Can someone please explain what is causing this difference and which of these is more accurate? Thanks.

Comment: Cross-posted:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085486/difference-in-kstat-and-sar-output